# How do I get the count of items in a list using Robot Framework?

Tags: robotframework

I have created a keyword saying

```
Select Topic

    [Arguments]  @{input}
    ${cnt}=  Get length   @{input}
    Log ${cnt}
```

And in another Robot Framework file I am calling the keyword with parameters as

```
 select topic  1 2 3 4
```

So the expected output is 4, but the result is shown as 7 (it is including the spaces).

Answer (score 7):

When you pass something like `1 2 3 4`, you are passing a single argument that is the literal string `1 2 3 4`. If you want to pass in a list of four or more arguments, you need two or more spaces between each argument:

Also, as a general rule you need to use `$` rather than `@` when trying to refer to an object itself. When you use `@`, robot will split the list into separate arguments.

Here's a working example. Notice the two spaces between each number when calling the keyword, and the use of `$` when calling `get length`:

```
*** Test Cases ***
test1
    Select Topic  1  2  3  4

*** Keywords ***
Select Topic
    [Arguments]    @{input}
    ${cnt}=    Get length    ${input}
    should be equal as numbers  ${cnt}  4
```

Comment: This uses the `*varargs` syntax which is described in the documentation for [variable arguments](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#variable-number-of-arguments) and more advanced examples in the [kwargs](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#kwargs-examples) section.

Answer (score 3):

The keyword is expecting one argument in list form. Robot Framework running the interpretation will throw an exception for invalid number of arguments. Create a list and pass it to the keyword.

The below solution should work for you:

```
**** Test Cases ***
test1
    ${List1}    Create List    1    2    3    4
    Select Topic    ${List1}

*** Keywords ***
Select Topic
    [Arguments]    @{input}
    ${cnt}=    Get length    @{input}
    Log     ${cnt}*
```